# ZSH avoid adding empty commands to history?

Tags: zsh

In zsh (with oh-my-zsh, is that matters) when I enter empty commands (e.g. just press enter) I see empty lines added to my `~/.zsh_history`:

```
: 1508496422:0;ls
: 1508496422:0;vim
: 1508496482:0;
: 1508496482:0;
: 1508496482:0;
: 1508496482:0;
: 1508496490:0;
: 1508496490:0;
: 1508496490:0;
: 1508496490:0;
: 1508496494:0;ls
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid adding these lines. I checked http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html but no luck. The reason why I'm trying to avoid adding empty lines is I'm using fzf and fzf lists these empty commands when I search in last commands in a directory.

If this is not possible in zsh side I'll try to search for a solution in fzf side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few Zsh settings to control what goes into your history
(though I'm surprised emtpies end up there; I can't reproduce that
despite also using fzf and hitting blank `RET`s a lot).

The man page for `zshoptions(1)` describes:

- `HIST_IGNORE_[ALL_]DUPS` — This should at least reduce your
  consecutive multiple empties down to one.
- `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` — Your empties might be treated as whitespace
  and thus be eliminated.  I like this feature anyway for intentionall
  discarding commands by starting them with a space.

There is also the `HISTORY_IGNORE` option (not to be confused with
Bash's `HISTIGNORE`) — described in `zshparam(1)` with an example —
which lets you remove a set of patterns.  An empty pattern may fix
your case.  It also has a `zshaddhistory` hook that you could use to
more finely control exactly what goes into history.

Comment: `HIST_IGNORE_[ALL_]DUPS` and `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` were already enabled. Adding `export HISTORY_IGNORE=""` did it for me. Thanks a lot!